# MAX44280 spice model gives wrong result when using dual supply

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm simulating the MAX44280 by using Maxim's model on LT-Spice.

[image]

When I simulate the op amp with single supply (`VDD=5V`, `VSS=0V`, `V+=2.5V`, `V-=VOUT`, `VOUT = RL(1k)` tied to `2.5V` ) the current consumption is `~800 uA`, which is correct.

However, when I partitioned the supply to `+/- 2.5V` the result is completely wrong. (`VDD=2.5V`, `VSS=-2.5V`, `V+=0V`, `V-=VOUT`, `VOUT = RL(1k)` tied to `GND`). In this case the current consumption is `1.3 mA`!

Could you please let me know if this spice model is wrong?  I'm planning to use this device with partitioned power supply.

Comment: The model can be broken. I needed to use simulated MAX999, and it does not perform properly. I asked Maxim Integrated's support, they confirmed the problem but there was no fix planned. Thus if it will appear that you wired everything correctly (per datasheet's specs) then it would be a good idea to ask MI support.

Answer (score 2):

It has been my experience that in simulations that you cannot always trust the power supply current of devices in subcircuits to be representative of actual real circuits unless the designer has paid particular attention to that part of the model.

I simulated a similar circuit to yours in LTSpice using an model from the manufacturer. The results of current flows in the circuits for all three are the same.

[image]

[image]

If you look closely the model for this opamp is predicting a VDD current of 169uA that falls almost directly in the middle of the range specified in the part data sheet.

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/16389fg-1267598.pdf)*</sup>

The conclusion here is that there is no funny business with LTSpice going on. It all depends upon the quality of the model and if it faithfully simulates the device supply current.

Comment: Yeah, besides if the simulated current itself is accurate or not, you get the same three values under different relative GNDs. But, in my case the value changes depending on where I set my GND.

I wonder if the model is connected to GND internally or the NMOS bulk is grounded internally

Here is the model
https://www.maximintegrated.com/content/dam/files/design/tools/modeling-simulation/spice/operational-amplifiers/macro/max44280.fam

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to consider here: -

1. The MAX44280 data sheet specifies a typical value of current consumption of 750 uA and a maximum value of 1200 uA (1.2 mA) but, this is on a power rail of 3.3 volts. Your power rail is 5 volts and therefore current may be somewhat higher.

[image]

2. Additionally, your LTSpice circuits are identical except that one is wholly shifted down by 2.5 volts - so, what you see is probably more an artefact of LTSpice rather than the model. After all, why should the power consumption of an op-amp change under static conditions when it is lifted by 2.5 volts or 2.5 million volts?

Comment: My question is related to "2.". Basically, the current must be the same under both conditions. I wonder if the model somehow is connected to GND internally. 

https://www.maximintegrated.com/content/dam/files/design/tools/modeling-simulation/spice/operational-amplifiers/macro/max44280.fam

Or maybe the NMOS bulk is connected to GND internally.